# SharedPreferences and Samsung S3

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have been trying to locate my SharedPreferences via Eclipse and Astro File Manager but have not had any luck.

I have looked in the following location but still cant located them.

```
/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/shared_prefs/
```

If I use my DroidX they are located in this directory.

This is how I save them

```
SharedPreferences prefs = Login.this.getSharedPreferences("mysharedprefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("username", username.getText().toString());
editor.putString("password", password.getText().toString());
editor.commit();
```

Is there a difference in how Samsung allows access to the file system that is different than for example Motorola DroidX?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

On Samsung devices you can find shared preferences in `/dbdata/databases/package.name/shared_prefs/package.name_preferences.xml`